# Proving inequality $\int_0^a f(x)dx \geq - t^2 f^\prime(t),~\forall t \in[0,a]$ under some properties of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis

For an $a>0$, let $f:[0,a]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex continuous function satisfying the following properties,

- $f(0) = 1$,
- $f(a) = 0$,
- $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ is non-decreasing continuous function,
- $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{d}{d x}f(x) = 0$.

I would like to show that $\int_0^a f(x) dx \geq - t^2 f^\prime(t),~\forall t\in[0,a]$.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say convex do you mean $f'' > 0$ ?

Comment: @Digitallis Yes, I considered $f^{\prime\prime}\geq0$, which can be seen from non-decreasing $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$.

Comment: My question is : may we assume that the function f' is differentiable ? That is, does $f''$ exist ? (in which case we will obvsly have $f'' \geq 0$)

Comment: @Digitallis Yes, we can assume that $f^{\prime\prime}$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist counterexamples, consider $a=1$ and

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}4(\sqrt3-2)x+1,\ &0\leq x<\sqrt3/2\\[.5em] 4(x-1)^2,&\sqrt3/2\leq x\leq1\end{matrix}\right.$$

This gives

$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}4(\sqrt3-2),\ &0\leq x<\sqrt3/2\\[.5em] 8(x-1),&\sqrt3/2\leq x\leq1\end{matrix}\right.$$

We can verify $f$ satisfies all $4$ conditions. However, we also have

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx\leq\frac12\quad\text{and}\quad-\left(\!\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{\!2}f'\!\!\left(\!\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\geq\frac34.$$

These two bounds can be easily checked on this [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t7nl6uzz1x). Hence we have $\int_0^1f(x)<-t^2f'(t)$ with $t=\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

---

The motivation behind this is that, we first consider the easiest case: $a=1$ and $f(x)=1-x$. Clearly $\int_0^af(x)=1/2<1=-a^2f'(a)$. Now $f$ satisfies all conditions except for $f'(a)=0$, which can be satisfied with a small mollifier around $a=1$. This gives the above example.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @sabo You are welcome